# can you release a game made by unity free on google play store

Tags: unity, publishing, google-play, unity-ads

do i need to pay for anything in this situation : i m making mini games to raise money and cant afford unity pro or plus(don't think its worth it)for my original idea/game.i am also thinking about using unity ads(is that free to use as well).

Comment: Did you check the terms of service for the version of Unity you're using? What do you they say? Is there a particular passage in them that you need help interpreting?

Comment: You might want to start reading and become familiar with the multitude of _Terms and Conditons_ and _Terms of Service_ and _End User Agreements_ of the services you'll be using before you start anything.

Comment: On top of other comments, it's only polite to spend some of your time googling your answer, and looking at Unity's website and ToS, before you ask strangers to spend theirs :)

Answer (score 2):

[It's all on the website](https://unity3d.com/unity).

> If your company currently makes more than $100k in annual gross
>   revenues or has raised funds in excess of $100k, you are not permitted
>   to use Unity Personal, for prototyping or otherwise, as defined in our
>   EULA Agreement. You may use Unity Plus for up to $200k in annual gross
>   revenues, or Unity Pro with an unlimited revenue or fundraising
>   capacity.

So yes, you can release your game made with the free Unity Personal Edition. You only need to upgrade to the next version after you made more than $100,000.